# RegEx question- Perl- search for last instance of string

Tags: regex, perl

This is probably very simple for all of the regex experts out there, but I've spent enough time driving myself mad trying to find the answer on my own.

I use Doc Parser, which lets you create text parsing rules. You can search using a regular expression. The documentation says PERL regular expressions are supported, and that the Regex 101 site is a good place to test your expressions, but I have found in the past that expressions that work in the Regex 101 don't always seem to work in Doc Parser.

I am trying to create an expression that searches for the last instance of one of three strings. The three strings are:

```
i am sitting with after this meeting are
won't be included in your published notes
Single Signal
```

The input text can look three different ways, this is why I'm looking for one of three strings. Here are three examples:

Ex 1:

```
Single Signal

Two things I am sitting with after this meeting are...

- Words words words
```

Ex 2:

```
Single Signal

- words words words
```

Ex 3:

```
Single Signal

words words that end in won't be included in your published notes.

- words
```

The three phrases I'm capturing end up being the starting point for what I'm really pulling out of the text.

I have used this as my core/root expression:

```
(?i)(i am sitting with after this meeting are|This is for internal
use and won't be included in your published notes|Single Signal)
```

And have tried various things at the end of the expression to indicate matching what occurs last/latest in the text.

```
(?i)(i am sitting with after this meeting are|This is for internal
use and won't be included in your published notes|Single Signal).*?

(?i)(i am sitting with after this meeting are|This is for internal
use and won't be included in your published notes|Single Signal)+

(?i)(i am sitting with after this meeting are|This is for internal
use and won't be included in your published notes|Single Signal){1}
```

This worked in Regex 101, PCRE2, but didn't work in Doc Parser (Perl):

```
(?i)[^(i am sitting with after this meeting are|won't be included in your published notes|Single Signal)]+$
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I reformatted your question so you can see the strings and examples better. Please ensure I understood correctly.

Comment: Put `.*` at the *beginning* of the regexp, not the end. That will skip over as much text as possible before matching one of the alternatives.

Comment: `This worked in Regex101` Nothing _works_ unless you post a _link_ to it.

Comment: @sln I'm not sure how to post a link to the test on regex101.com.

Comment: _Save Regex_ top left button. Copy link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefix your initial regex with `.*` (or perhaps `.*\K`), there can be at most one match, so the correct value should be captured.

```
$ perl -e '
    $t = "1a 2a 3a 1b 2b 1c 3c 2d";
    $t =~ /.*(1.|2.|3.)/;
    print "matched $1\n" 
'
matched 2d
$
```

You may need to adjust so the prefix also capture newlines.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I'm new to writing on Stack Overflow. I think this is the closest to the right answer; adding what worked for me.

I was wrong about it being in Perl. It's in PCRE.

I needed to encapsulate the statement in / and end with / .

I needed the negative lookback and across lines functionality.

What worked: 
/(?s:.*\s)\K(i am sitting with after this meeting are|included in your published notes.|Single Signal)(?!.*(i am sitting with after this meeting are|your published notes|Single Signal))/

This helped:
https://www.xlayer.co.za/forum/viewtopic.php?id=105

Answer (score 3):

Match "globally" -- find all matches in the string -- and capture the match. Then the regex keeps going through the string but as it goes it can only capture the current match so we end up with the last one.  In Perl syntax

```
/(one|two|three)/g
```

This ends up having in a capture variable whichever of the three sub-patterns matches *in the last match* (when used in list context)/

An example

```
my $text = q(hi one some two or three and two more);

my @captures = $text =~ /(one|two|three)/g;

# $1 == 'two'
```

and the `$1` (capture) variable has the string `two`.  (And so does the last element of the array but I expect that tool to not have a capability to create variables and capture into them.)

The assignment to an array forces the regex into a "list context," in which it continues matching through the whole string; thus we get the last capture as needed.  (One doesn't have to actually assign to an array, forcing a list context in any way is sufficient.)

I don't know what that "Doc Parser" is or how it works so I don't know how to force a regex variant used in that tool to behave like above but I'd imagine that it's possible.

Comment: @ChrisCharley I believe the match needs be done in list context. eg: `seq 20| perl -e '$/=undef; $_=<>; ()=/(3|13|19)/g; print $1'`

Comment: @jhnc  Yes, but I dropped a part of it  (just put it back in), trying to distill it to regex only  -- because I expect that "Doc Parser" (which I have no idea about) probably can't use language features of any programming language.  Since it can use regex I assume that it can use a capture group in some form.  But then I don't know how to ensure in that tool that the matching keeps going through the string, so the application of the idea here does depend on the tool...  Edited.

Comment: @AprilUrban Updated answer (yesterday)

Comment: Thanks for this, it's helpful info that helped me understand regex more and got me on the right path.